# Blazor Server - component is updating wrong client with data

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server application that will always have 2 clients connected with known static IPs.

The application connects to 2 external servers, each running CasparCG and we get OSC messages back and I need to send the data from the messages back to the correct UI.

The messages are being received by a service class injected as scoped, so each client should get their own instance and it checks the incoming message, see's if it's for the client who's instance it is, and sends it to an event handler.

The component that the user is looking at is hooked up to that event handler and is updating the parameters in the component and calling InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); to update the UI.

Everything works fine when I connect the first client, however when I connect the 2nd, the UI isn't updated, instead, the 1st client UI is updated with the data.

This is the method in my service which is injected as scoped:

```
public async void PlaybackClipTimeEvent(object sender, PlaybackClipTimeEventArgs e)
        {
            //check if the message is for this client
            if (_channelsProvider.CasparChannels.Any(x => x.CasparChannelId == e.ChannelId))
            {

                var sp = sender.GetType().GetProperty("CasparCgOscListener").GetValue(sender);
                int sourcePort = (int)sp.GetType().GetProperty("OscServerPort").GetValue(sp);

                var cc = _channelsProvider.CasparChannels.Where(x => x.CasparChannelId == e.ChannelId && x.OscPort == sourcePort).FirstOrDefault();
                

                var uiCh = cc.UiChannelId;

                //just a task to calculate times
                var times = await CalculateClipTime(e.TotalSeconds, e.SecondsElapsed);


                var tsData = new CasparTimeStampData()
                {
                    UiChannelId = uiCh,
                    TotalClipTime = times[0],
                    TotalElapsedTime = times[1]
                };


                //Invoke event handler
                OscEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new OscEventHandler(tsData ));
            }



        }
```

The component is hooked up to the event handler in the OnAfterRenderAsync override method:
`_oscMessageService.OscEventHandler += _casparCommunicationManager_OscEventHandler;`

Then this is the method to deal with the event:

```
private async void _casparCommunicationManager_OscEventHandler(object? sender, OscEventHandler e)
        {

            switch (e.Timestamps.UiChannelId)
            {
                case 1:
                    channel1TotalTime = e.Timestamps.TotalClipTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    channel1TimeCode = e.Timestamps.TotalElapsedTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    channel2TotalTime = e.Timestamps.TotalClipTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    channel2TimeCode = e.Timestamps.TotalElapsedTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    channel3TotalTime = e.Timestamps.TotalClipTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    channel3TimeCode = e.Timestamps.TotalElapsedTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    channel4TotalTime = e.Timestamps.TotalClipTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    channel4TimeCode = e.Timestamps.TotalElapsedTime;
                    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
                    break;
            }
```

I'm not sure why the UI for client 1 is updating when I press play on client 2 UI and start getting messages back. I thought because the service that receives and invokes the event handler is scoped, the component should only update the client for that scope.

Comment: 1. You are overcomplicating things. There is no need for using onafterrenderasync anywhere in this case. 2. Read about WeakReferenceMessenger in the MVVM Community Toolkit. Perhaps, a solution is  - sign up each client with specific channel and listen on only those channels.